# CSS - sticky positioning of more than one row

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to lock certain amount of rows to be "fixed" when scrolling a table. The problems:
1) The number of rows to be locked vary (not always only the column headers) so cannot rely on fixed number.
2) The height of each row may vary depend on content, so it is not equally height and not any known value.
3) As the table and content are dynamically created and can be modified on runtime, a responsive solution will be the best.

Given the following CSS (assume all rows in thead are to be "locked"):

```
thead th{ position:sticky; }
```

And then the JavaScript approach (tbl is the table element):

```
var i,j,h=0,r; // Set the "top" of next "locked" rows
for(i=0 ; i<tbl.thead.rows.length ; i++) {
    r=tbl.thead.rows[i];
    for(j=0 ; j<r.cells.length ; j++)
        r.cells[j].style.top=h+"px";
    h+=r.offsetHeight;
}
```

The main issue: I prefer to do it ALL using CSS (if possible).
The best "solution" I have come up can only remove the inner loop, but using dynamically controlled <style> element (assuming stl is the handle to the STYLE element):

```
var rules="",i,h=0; // Set the "top" of next "locked" rows
for(i=0 ; i<tbl.thead.rows.length ; i++) {
    rules+="thead tr:nth-child("+(i+1)+") th{ top:"+h+"px; }\n";
    h+=tbl.thead.rows[i].offsetHeight;
}
/*
I know is possible to use stl.sheet.insertRule(),
but as I overwrite ALL rules whenever there is change, I have chosen this way.
*/
stl.innerHTML=rules;
```

However, that requires as many rules as header rows.

The question: Any solution to make ONE RULE that can create the same effect?
Is it possible to achieve it with pure CSS (responsive solution)?

**Note:** The table can have any position on page, but is inside a container with overflow:auto.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

There is a very easy solution, make thead sticky and not the individual rows

```css
.container {
    height: 250px;
    width: 200px;
    overflow: auto;
}

th {
    height: 60px;
}


#second {
    height: 80px;
    background-color: lightblue;
}

thead {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>h row 1</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th id="second">h row 2</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>
        <td>data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>l data</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: As per the following link: https://caniuse.com/#search=sticky - this solution may not work on Chrome. If I want to programmatically detect if it works or not (to implement the fallback), I believe it will be a bit hard... However, on FF/Safari it works, tested.

Comment: You are right, it's broken on Chrome, and doesn't look like they will fix it. Bad luck !